# sql Query to find the maximium hour of particular event in table

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have a single table with fields (crime-id int , crime_time timestamp , crime string, city string )

There are only 9 unique crimes in table . I need to find the Time ie the hour in which a particular crime occured frequency in max times . Eg if  Robbery cause most between 10- 11 it must show 10 or 11 ... the time may start from 00:00 nd ends in 23:59

Comment: are you looking for a sql query ?

Comment: Ya im working in Hive it has HQL so if there is an sql query i can convert it to HQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viod answer is almost ok.

But you need a group by to count the robbery in time slot.

Also need put an alias for the subquery.

```
SELECT  period, max(nb)
FROM (
        SELECT extract(hour from crime_time) as period, count(*) as nb
        FROM crimes    
        WHERE crime_string = 'Robbery'
        GROUP BY extract(hour from crime_time)   
    ) as  subquery_alias
GROUP BY period
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do, but I have not tested it (and you may have to find hive equivalents of the postgres function I use: `extract` (doc is available here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
SELECT max(nb), period
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as nb, period
    FROM (
        SELECT crime_string, extract(hour from crime_time) as period
        FROM crimes
        WHERE crime_string = 'Robbery'
    )
    GROUP BY period
);
```